# Problems with sign in with Rails 4, Devise and CanCan

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm pretty new to Rails and Devise.  I'm having problems signing in/up.  When trying to signin, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_in
```

The show action in Users Controller is the following:

```
def show
  authorize! :show, current_user
  render 'profile_page'
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my route.rb:
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
get 'users/:id' => 'users#show'
resources :users
get 'users/edit'

controller :static_pages do
  get :home
  get 'show' =>'users/show'
end

resources :posts do 
  resources :comments
end
scope '(:locale)' do
  resources :posts
end

devise_for :users do 
 get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
 get 'users/:id' => 'users#show'
end

authenticated :user do
   root :to => 'posts#index', as: :authenticated_root
end

resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create] do
  root :to => 'static_pages#home'
end

controller :static_pages do
  get :home
  get 'about' =>'static_pages#about'
  get 'about_class' => 'static_pages#about_class'
  get 'schedule_class' =>'static_pages#schedule_class'
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails is looking for `users/:id` likely with the users#show action when you are probably entering `users/sign_in` into your browser. Your routes need to be adjusted.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I've tried a variety of things. Could you take another look now that I've added the routes and elaborate on your answer or give me another pointer?  Again, any further information or help would be greatly appreciated.